# segmentation error, search return error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to design an address book, trying to do a search, but I keep getting a segmentation error. I know what this means but why is it trying to allocate memory that is in use? Why is it not searching?

Here is the code:

```
class contact{

private:

    string fn="", ln="", email="", number="";

public:
    void input();
    void output();
    void setfname(string f_n);
    void setlname(string l_n);

    void setemail(string emaila);

    void setnumber(string num);
    string getfname();
    string getlname();

    string getemail();

    string getnumber();

contact();
contact(string f_n, string l_n, string emaila,string num);

};
void menu(string opt);

int search_contacts( contact contacts[],int MAX, string search);



int main(){

    string search;

    const int MAX=2;

    contact contacts[MAX];

    cout << "Enter up to " << MAX << " contacts.\n";

    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX; i++)

    {

     contacts[0].input();

    }

    [menu function goes here]

     contacts[0].output();

return 0;

}
 int search_contacts(contact contacts[],int size, string search)

{
 cout << "Search contact by LastName:____  ";

 cin >> search;

  bool lookup = false;

  for(int index=0;index<size;index++)

    {

      if(contacts[index].getlname() == search)

     { 

      lookup = true;

      cout<<"Result found "<<endl;

      break;

    }

     }

if(!lookup)

cout<<"no record found"<<endl;

}

void menu(string opt){
 string search;
contact contacts[0];
const int MAX = 2;

[show menu msg...here]

     cin>>opt;

// do this if the option selected is search 

if(opt=="search")

  {

    search_contacts(contacts, MAX, search);

}
[more menu code]
}
void contact::input()
{

cout<<"fn and ln separate by a space: ";

cin>>fn>>ln;

cout<<"email: ";

cin>>email;

cout<<"phone number: ";

cin>>number;

}

void contact::output()
{
[output code... goes here];

}
string contact::getlname()
{

return ln;

}

[functions that delegates the variables...goes here]
```

Comment: Have you run this through a debugger to find where the problem is?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you should learn how to use a debugger to determine why you get the segmentation fault.

It looks to me that you are trying to do operations on contacts that don't exist. I see a zero-length array in `menu()` and I don't see how you got the contacts you created in `main()` to the `menu()` function and hence to your search function.

If you try to do operations on uninitialized objects, you'll see a segmentation fault like this.

Comment: Indeed, this is most probably the problem. You give a zero-sized array to the search function, but set the size argument to two. This cannot work. One more hint: use vector instead of arrays, they are much easier to handle!

Answer (score 0):

You cant do a string comparison using == which you have done when you match opt to "search" and try to find matching names.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: Yes, this was another obvious problem that I saw. The pointer to the search string is what will be compared using `==`. It will never be equal to the pointer in the contact list.

Comment: I don't see the `strcmp` function in the post.  The "current post" uses `std::string`, which allows the `operator==()`.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks, I think you're right. (I'm more of a C person, so I overlooked the use of `string`.) That would make this answer incorrect. For the record, use of `==` is a glaring error in C or Java. In C++ or C# I think it's fine. (though in C# it made me cringe, coming from a Java background!)